# Can I autogenerate/compile code on-the-fly, at runtime, based upon values (like key/value pairs) parsed out of a configuration file?

Tags: vb.net

This might be a doozy for some.  I'm not sure if it's even 100% implementable, but I wanted to throw the idea out there to see if I'm really off of my rocker yet.

I have a set of classes that mimics enums (see my other questions for specific details/examples).  For 90% of my project, I can compile everything in at design time.  But the remaining 10% is going to need to be editable w/o re-compiling the project in VS 2010.  This remaining 10% will be based on a templated version of my Enums class, but will generate code *at runtime*, based upon data values sourced in from external configuration files.

To keep this question small, see [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4446341/are-generic-operator-overloads-allowed-in-net-4) for an idea of what my Enums class looks like.  The templated fields, per that question, will be the `MaxEnums` Int32, `Names` String() array, and `Values` array, plus each shared implementation of the `Enums` sub-class (which themselves, represent the Enums that I use elsewhere in my code).

I'd ideally like to parse values from a simple text file (INI-style) of key/value pairs:

```
[Section1]
Enum1=enum_one
Enum2=enum_two
Enum3=enum_three
```

So that the following code would be generated (and compiled) at runtime (comments/supporting code stripped to reduce question size):

```
Friend Shared ReadOnly MaxEnums As Int32 = 3

Private Shared ReadOnly _Names As String() = New String() _
    {"enum_one", "enum_two", "enum_three"}

Friend Shared ReadOnly Enum1 As New Enums(_Names(0), 1)
Friend Shared ReadOnly Enum2 As New Enums(_Names(1), 2)
Friend Shared ReadOnly Enum3 As New Enums(_Names(2), 4)

Friend Shared ReadOnly Values As Enums() = New Enums() _
    {Enum1, Enum2, Enum3}
```

I'm certain this would need to be generated in MSIL code, and I know from reading that the two components to look at are `CodeDom` and `Reflection.Emit`, but I was wondering if anyone had working examples (or pointers to working examples) versus really long articles.  I'm a hands-on learner, so I have to have example code to play with.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [Compiler Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kss697ez%28v=VS.71%29.aspx) to compile the code into a dll.  Then just dynamically load the assembly at run-time.

Comment: This appears to be deprecated in .NET 4.0.  MSDN states it's been replaced by the [CSharpCodeProvider Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.csharp.csharpcodeprovider%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) instead.  But this raises a question -- Can doing it this way avoid tripping up anti-virus alarms or other host-based intrusion detection systems?  I only thought about that last night, hence I forgot to inquire in my original question.  This would really be one highly-useful case for inline MSIL functionality.

Comment: I realized (much to my amusement), that I am over-engineering a solution here.  I found a suitable approach that doesn't involve designing code templates and doing on-the-fly compilation.  But at least I know of the CSharpCodeProvider Class now, on the off chance I find a need for it later on.  Thanks!